# Clarification of use of Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to clarify the use of the Cauchy-Riemann equations in showing *where* a complex function is differentiable. 
I have a theorem which states,

> "If two real-valued continuous functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ of two
>   real variables $x$ and $y$ have continuous first partial derivatives
>   that satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations in some domain $D$, then the
>   complex function $f(x) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ is analytic in $D$."

Say I have the function
$$
f(x+iy) = (x^2+y^2)+i(y^2-x^2)
$$
and I want to find out, where and if it is analytic. Taking partial derivatives gives
$$
u_x=2x, v_y=2y\\
u_y=2y, -v_x=-(-2x)=2x
$$
If I equate these according to the Cauchy-Riemann equations, and rearrange the terms, I have
$$
u_x=v_y\\
2x=2y\\
y=x\\
u_y=-v_y\\
2y=2x\\
y=x
$$

Does this imply that this function is analytic in the domain defined by the line through the origin $y=x$?
Or must the equations *strictly* satisfy the CR equations, ie. no rearranging is allowed?

Basically, what I'm asking is, if the CR equations come out unequal, but we rearrange the terms to find a domain where the equations are true, does this mean that the function is differentiable over that domain?

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that "domain" is *usually* required to be open, and any open subset of $\,\Bbb C\,$ will have points $\;(x,y)\;$with $\,x\neq y\;$ ...

Comment: `Does this imply that this function is analytic in the domain defined by the line through the origin`. That set is not a domain.

Comment: Okay, I see, they do say that "An open and connected set is called a domain". Let me see if I can word this correctly. Whilst it is connected, In this case, since y=x is not open, that is, it does not have a neighborhood consisting of points that belong to y=x, in fact, it does not have a neighborhood at all. Is that right?

Comment: What do you mean by "no rearranging is allowed"?

Comment: What I meant by that was that both sides of the equation had to be equal in and of themselves, e.g. $u_x=x=v_y$.
I can see that my misunderstanding with regards to what a domain is caused my confusion.